# How to replace colon and remove extra spaces?

Tags: jquery, replace

Sure, I can make it work, with 2 `replace()` entries, but is there a way for me to aggregate the two replaces? I need every colon and every extra space (but not the one space between words, just the white space) to be removed from the text string.

```
$(this).text().replace(':', '').replace(/\s+/g, " ");
```

Comment: I think the two replaces are perfectly clear. You can do it with one replace but why? (By the way, the first replace only replaces the _first_ occurance of a colon, is this intentional?)

Comment: Or to `$(this).text(function(_,t) {return t.replace(':', '').replace(/\s+/g, " ")});` if the code is supposed to do something.

Answer (score 2):

`/\s*:|\s+(?=\s)/g` what about this regex, does it fit your needs? Used via `text.replace('/\s*:|\s+(?=\s)/g', '');`

It looks for `:` optionally preceeded by whitespaces or whitespaces that are followed by whitespaces.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YtKFm/)
[Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/LRZ4xA4nDB)

Note that in order for the text to be changed, you have to change your code :

```
$(this).text(function(_,t) {return t.replace(/\s*:|\s+(?=\s)/g, "")});
```

#### #Edit

Obviously my regex is much more complex than the original one, it is by far not as readable as the double replace but it is still faster: http://jsperf.com/regorreplac (thanks to @dystroy for that comparison). With the right comments in your source code explaining what the regex does there is nothing to be said against using it.

Comment: OP is looking for a more elegant solution, not a more convoluted one.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine it seems to me like he is looking to get away from 2 replace calls and just wants one, that is what i provide with this code.

Comment: +1 A comment to explain that OP's code is clearer than a complex regex would have made this answer better but it's a correct and appropriate answer for this precise question.

Comment: @dystroy i agree: what he wants in the end is not easier than what he already has.

Comment: @dystroy i added what you suggested in some way and additionally included your speed-comparison from your other comment, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have to ask yourself, what is more important: **readability**, or **time consumption**? A single regex would be quicker, but far less readable (in my opinion). If you're using this on smaller bodies of strings, I doubt the cost difference is going to be significant at all, but on larger strings, and where time is of the upmost importance, perhaps it is worth considering the single regex. I'd still suggest that it's unlikely to be the case (given this exact example), and so *in general* I'd advise you to stick with your original code.

@luk2302's single regex solution works perfectly, so if you *must* go for a single solution, then go with that. Initially I actually thought that a single more-complex regex would take longer to load than a single string replace followed by a single simple regex. However, this was based off some misguided notion, [which has been debunked by @dystroy](http://jsperf.com/regorreplac/3) (Thanks BTW, I wonder if this scales linearly).

Comment: I don't like this answer. While it's true that OP's code is clearer, you might not know how regex work : they were designed from the start to be fast and they're fast (at least the versions without back reference). Here, luk2302 solution is faster : http://jsperf.com/regorreplac

Comment: Wow, thanks @dystroy for this - I suppose there's a lot of stigma surrounding the over-use of Regexs to the extent that I just (naively) thought that that would be the case in this example. I stand by my argument that it's a lot less clear, but I suppose if this operation was time critical then you could opt for the single regex. This is why I love SO :)

Comment: I see. But you don't have to insist so much on the fact you were wrong, that's not interesting to readers. I would reverse the order of the paragraphs to put the accent on what is a valid point : the two replace are more readable.